# IIS can not access newly added files in a django project

Tags: python, django, iis

In a django project that is served by IIS (windows), i added a local file, test.py. The project ran perfectly before and still runs perfect on localhost, however IIS appears to not recognize the new test.py file. It appears IIS access to this file fails, even if the users IUSR and IIS_USRS have full access (same as for all other files in the folder).

I get below error message, and somethimes also the same but "No module named 'app.test'. Removing the "import app.test as test" in views.py solves the issue.
Suprisingly the "import app.oldFile as oldFile" works without issue.

[image]

In my views.py, i import the python scripts like this

```
import app.oldFile as oldFile
import app.test as test
```

My django project has the structure:

```
djangoRest
 -app
  --__init__.py
  --views.py
  --oldFile.py
  --test.py
 -djangoRest
  --__init__.py
  --settings.py
  --urls.py
  --wsgi.py
```

Comment: Maybe the name of the test file is causing some unknown problem with IIS module recognition. But this is less likely because I don't have this problem when I use test as the file name. So I think you can rebuild and deploy this project. Or create a simple empty project, cause test.py in view.py inside and see if this problem persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason, and solution.

In the earlier import file oldFile.py i use the line

```
import os
os.chdir(r\\some\\other\\directory\\)
```

This obviously changes the current working directory and as a result the other file test.py can't be found, and cannot be imported.

This mistake does not matter when testing django on the localhost, but only manifests in an issue when served by IIS.